# Indexing n-dimenasional arrays without for loops in LabVIEW

Tags: arrays, indexing, labview

Is there any VI in LabVIEW or an algorithm, which will let me index an n-dimensional array without using for loops?

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of operation you want to do? The short answer is "probably no, but the LabVIEW compiler is pretty good at optimising for loops", but if you can be more specific then there might be a better answer (and you might get upvotes instead of downvotes on your question).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the elements you want, you can use the [`Index Array`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/index_array/) VI.

[image]